# Selenium scrolling to bottom of page occasionally stops

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

I have a page that can be scrolled down "infinitely" (for illustration, I will use the page https://www.reuters.com/news/us, which reveals more older news items every time you scroll to the bottom of the page). I want to scroll down to the bottom of the page to load older items many times using selenium. The following code works in principle:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/bernhardclemm/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.reuters.com/news/us')

# Accept Cookies
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
cookies = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='_evidon-banner-acceptbutton']")))
cookies.click()

# Switch of "Photos" to speed up loading
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
photos_off = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(),'Photos')]")))
photos_off.click()

# Scroll down 100 times
i  = 1
while i < 500:
    print(i)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

As you can see in the following GIF, for every turn in the loop (`i` printed in the Python console to the right), the Selenium driver scrolls down once (Google Chrome in the left).

[image]

However, sometimes the Selenium driver has reached the bottom of the page but no new content loads, like this GIF shows. Note how the loop is still running in Python:

[image]

When I scroll up a bit in Chrome *manually*, the automatic scrolling starts again. So this is **not** because the site has reached the end of its contents.

Any idea whether this is due to the web site or a flaw in my code? If it's a something about the web site, what would be a way to avoid the problem with Selenium?

Comment: Did u find the answer? i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I haven't looked into it further...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest check the `Loading more` div element to disappear.
Use `try..except` block check If it not find the element `Loading more` the do a bit `scroll up` the page.The execution time will be a bit more.However you will achieve what you are after.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/bernhardclemm/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.reuters.com/news/us')

# Accept Cookies - you will have to adapt the XPATH to your system language
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
cookies = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton")))
cookies.click()

# Scroll down 100 times
i  = 1

while i < 500:
    print(i)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    i += 1
    try:
       WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'Loading more')]")))
    except:
        print('Re-try.........')
        #scroll page up to certain limit
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.UP)
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Output**:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
Re-try.........
30
31
32
33
Re-try.........
34
35
36
37
38
Re-try.........
39
40
41
Re-try.........
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
Re-try.........
81
82
83
84
85
Re-try.........
86
87
88
Re-try.........
89
90
91
Re-try.........
92
Re-try.........
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
Re-try.........
104
105
106
107
Re-try.........
108
Re-try.........
109
110
Re-try.........
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
Re-try.........
118
119
Re-try.........
120
121
122
123
Re-try.........
124
Re-try.........
125
126
127
128
Re-try.........
129
130
Re-try.........
131
132
133
134
Re-try.........
135
136
137
Re-try.........
138
Re-try.........
139
140
141
Re-try.........
142
143
Re-try.........
144
Re-try.........
145
Re-try.........
146
147
148
Re-try.........
149
Re-try.........
150
Re-try.........
151
152
Re-try.........
153
154
Re-try.........
155
Re-try.........
156
Re-try.........
157
158
Re-try.........
159
Re-try.........
160 and son on...
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts - this makes intuitive sense. But unfortunately, the problem shows up again sometimes - without `except` being called.

Comment: @broti : can you try this instead of  `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.UP) ` to make page up try this `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,-250);")` and let me know how this goes?

Comment: Unfortunately, the driver still gets stuck sometimes at the bottom of the page, and the exception is not called... Is there perhaps away to occasionally check whether the driver does any scrolling down at all, and if not, scroll up?

Comment: @broti : Not sure buddy I can reach 500 times without problem with both conditions.possibly network issue or  something else that i couldn't trace.I have to disappoint you.

Comment: @broti, you can always check what is the current height of the page, if current height is equal to the previous height you can stop or try something else.