# The ScrollIntoView () function that scrolls in an IFrame using Selenium crashes after a long period of work

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

**Description of the situation:** I have a script that extract conversations using Selenium. The message list is in an IFrame that contains about 30 items that are updated at each scroll. The list does not expand but is updated. The structure of the DOM does not increase either.

**Problem Description:** The problem arises when the conversation is extremely big. After a few hours of work, the scroll button reaches the top and does not update. At this point scrollIntoView() cannot scroll, although the conversation has not ended.

"Load more data" or other triggers that can be caught do not appear in this lock point, I analyzed and searched the whole structure, but it is not present. I also simulated this lock manually, when the scroll bar crashes I scroll down a bit manually after which the new conversations are loaded.

**Example in code:**

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"chat-pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollHeight;")

all_msgs_loaded = False

while not all_msgs_loaded:

    li_elements: List[WebElement] = self._driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-tid='chat-pane-item']")
    # more code ...
    self._driver.execute_script(
                """
                try {
                    document.querySelector('li[data-tid=\"chat-pane-item\"]').scrollIntoView();
                } catch (error) {         
                    document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"message-pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollTop=document.body.scrollHeight;  
                }
                finally {
                    document.querySelector('li[data-tid=\"chat-pane-item\"]').scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();      
                }
                """)

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"chat-pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollHeight;")
    if new_height == last_height:
        all_msgs_loaded = True
    last_height = new_height
```

The try-catch method works but is not stable. When Scrollbar crashes, scrollIntoView cannot scroll, and the combination `document.querySelector('div[data-tid=\"message-pane-list-viewport\"]').scrollTop=document.body.scrollHeight;` it forces it in a way, as if I were scrolling manually.

But after a while I get `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300,000` at one point I execute the scroll script.

**Similar situations found:** I also found this post [Selenium scrolling to bottom of page occasionally stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61057333/selenium-scrolling-to-bottom-of-page-occasionally-stops)
The problem is very similar but there appears the trigger "Load more data" which can be controlled.

This is what the scroll bar lock looks like.

[image]

In this situation, if I scroll manual down a bit, it returns to normal. But in the case of the script, scrolling down is not performed when scrolling is blocked by **scrollIntoView(false);**

**Can you please tell me if there are other ways to simulate forced scrolling?** Method with `scrollTop=document.body.scrollHeight;` works but is not stable.

When the script runs for a few hours and I see that the scrollbar has crashed and scrollIntoView() cannot scroll. I'm waiting for a while for the exception to appear, and I'm trying to scroll up with the mouse, and the new messages are already loaded, but scrollIntoView() is already blocked and doing nothing, and the error appears.

Comment: If the DOM gets too big it will crash, you should find another way to get what you want.

Comment: Hello @pguardiario , the structure of the DOM does not increase at all. Only the list in the IFrame is updated when scrolling, no other elements are added, only the update from the server.